# image does not load from sub-directory unless it has file type .ico

Tags: php, image

I have a very odd situation, which I have explored with my hosting provider who says it is coding problem, but I don't see how. The example code below illustrates the problem as loading a background image, but it applies as a problem to loading any image.  The code snippets (taken directly from the browser source code listing) with the results are shown below,

```
1. background-image: url(group_images_001.ico);
2. background-image: url(group_images_001.jpg);
3. background-image: url(member/images/pr_sized/group_images_001.ico);
4. background-image: url(member/images/pr_sized/group_images_001.jpg);
```

Snippets 1, 2 and 3 work; 4 does not. I have set up 4 identical scripts with the appropriate coding changes above and image files so I can run the tests in parallel.  So images load when in the same directory as the script, but only from a sub-directory when they have a file type of .ico.  The image files are all jpegs, I have just given them a file type of .ico or .jpg.  Am I sure that I have the correct names for the image files? I have script 3 working with .ico and I have renamed it to .jpg and script 4 then fails.  I have tried changing the file type of the .ico to .jpg and I am told the file already exists.  I have tried a file type of .jpeg just in case and it still fails.

I'm running in a shared hosting environment, but have now run out of possible coding errors. I have the same effect with an ordinary img tag. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Probably a `file does not exist` error, check browser developer tools (networks tab).

Comment: No it's not a not found or permissions problem as I can change the filetype in the script from .ico. to .jpg and change the rename the file in the directory from .ico to .jpg and it fails.  Nothing else has changed.  I change it all back again it works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that group_images_001.jpg is readable by all users, and  you can try adding quotes around the path:

```
background-image: url("member/images/pr_sized/group_images_001.jpg");
```

Comment: Inspect your web page a look if it's give you an error as Not founded or forbidden ?

Comment: No it's not a not found or permissions problem as I can change the filetype in the script from .ico. to .jpg and change the rename the file in the directory from .ico to .jpg and it fails.  Nothing else has changed.  I change it all back again it works!